# Suppress hyperref unicode warning

Tags: hyperref, warnings

Code:

```
\documentclass[pdftitle=abc]{article}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

Log:

```
Package hyperref Warning: XeTeX driver only supports unicode.
(hyperref)                Enabling option `unicode'.
```

I'm not sure why `hyperref` warns me when I have passed `unicode` option. I know it's `pdftitle` creating the warning and it can be suppressed by a `unicode` option before `pdftitle` in the global option list. But I really hate local options not taking precedence over global ones. I'd like to understand what's happening here and if it's a bug.

I forgot to mention: I'm compiling the file with `xelatex`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not really a bug, but history: The default value of `unicode` is currently `false`, but with `xelatex`  `hyperref` had to force the value to `true` and so issues a warning when it switches it (which happens when it encounters your `pdftitle`).

The `unicode` option is unneeded with xelatex (as it is forced anyway), but currently the only way to avoid the warning is to explicitly use `unicode` *before* all keys which set text.

We will change the behaviour in the next hyperref version.